# How can I overcome PhpStorm unnecessary one-line 'if' statement formatting in PHP?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 2016.3.1 for both JavaScript and PHP. While in case of JavaScript it is possible to set PhpStorm to preserve one-line formatting of 'if' statements, - in PHP - reformatting of 'if' statements forces them into two-line way. Like this:

`if(true) console.log('Hello');` // in JavaScript

```
if(false)
    echo 'Hello'; // in PHP
```

It's a bit irritating. - Any advice to overcome this behavior?

Comment: It may be a bit irritating at first, but it makes it more readable and cleaner.

Comment: Have you tried this option? Settings → Editor → Code Styles → PHP → Wrapping and Braces → 'if()' statement → Force braces: do not force. This doesn't add a line break for one-line-statements.

Comment: It's not so in PhpStorm 2016.3.1

Comment: @charlotte It depends...

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14587 & https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14522 perhaps -- watch them (star/vote./comment) to get notified on any progress. But overall -- consider using PSR-x for code formatting and stuff -- helps a lot other devs who will be dealing with your code later.

Comment: PSR-2 [requires](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#5-control-structures) enclosing the body of control structures into curly braces. It's more readable and less-error prone.